# Is there any shutdown event at Azure function app level?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-async

I would like to do some clean up of resources (e.g. remove of subscriptions) before entirely shutting down of the Azure function app.

Is there any provider to listen to shutdown events of the host of Azure function app? I can only find the startup file for dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

For C# Class Library functions, [Cancellation Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#cancellation-tokens) are supported but the other languages don't have anything similar AFAIK.